# Showing Image in ImageView from Internet by using Glide

Tags: android, android-glide

I am learning Android Glide I am creating a simple app which shows image from web to imageview using Glide but everytime it crashes when i run this app

MainActivity.java code

```
package com.example.cs.myglideapp;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageView img1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        img1 = findViewById(R.id.img1);

        // urls to show on imageview
        //String[] urls = {
            //"https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/03/04/01/46/bottles-1235327_960_720.jpg",
            //"https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/06/24/23/41/beer-2439237_960_720.jpg"};

        //loading image into ImageView 
        Glide.with(this)
            .load("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/03/04/01/46/bottles-1235327_960_720.jpg")
            .into(img1);
    }
}
```

Comment: buil.gradle->  dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1'
}

Comment: add setContentView() method in your onCreate() method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to add `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

```
package com.example.cs.myglideapp;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageView img1;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); // Add this line

        img1 = findViewById(R.id.img1);

        //loading image into ImageView 
       Glide.with(this).load("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/03/04/01/46/bottles-1235327_960_720.jpg").into(img1);

    }
}
```

Comment: i think i messed up with my code..its working now thank u